# Sorting DataGridTextColumn by Int or Float value instead of raw string sort

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid and programmatically generating the columns with code-behind.
The columns are derived from DataGridTextColumn with some additions for locking key input to a specific type.

I need the columns to sort numerically:

```
1
2
10
11
```

instead of the default string based sort:

```
1
10
11
2
```

I've tried a DataGridSortingEvent, but it fails to cast from BindingListCollectionView to IList

```
ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView((IList)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource));
```

Here's how I'm creating the DataGrid

```
DataSet set = new DataSet();
set.ReadXml(xmlDocument.CreateReader());

DataView data = set.Tables["row"];

dataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
```

Here's the block where I'm creating the columns

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataChimpIntegerColumn()
                            {
                                Header = column.ColumnTitle,
                                Binding = new Binding(column.ColumnTitle),
                                MaxWidth = 150,
                                DefaultValue = column.ColumnDefault,
                            });
```

And the event block

```
private void dataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridColumn column = e.Column;
    IComparer comparer = null;

    if (e.Column.SortMemberPath != "id") return;

    e.Handled = true;

    ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) 
        ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

    column.SortDirection = direction;

    //    Error --> 
    ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView((IList)CollectionViewSource
        .GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource));

    comparer = new SortNumerical(direction);

    lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
}
```

The exact error message is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView' to type 'System.Collections.IList'.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works.

Changing the ItemsSource type to `ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>` allowed me to dynamically create classes according to the XML file loaded (thanks C# 6).

I could then directly use `ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(xmlData.ItemsSource as IList);`

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

During creation of the columns you should be able to specify the `SortMemberPath` because your custom column is deriving from `DataGridTextColumn`. However this does mean you have to have access to the integer representation of the value you want to sort by.

In my test I came up with this programmatic initialization of the columns:

```
this.deviceLogDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "Error Number",
    Binding = new Binding(nameof(DeviceLogRowVM.ErrorNumberString)),
    MaxWidth = 150,
    // DefaultValue = column.ColumnDefault,
    SortMemberPath = nameof(DeviceLogRowVM.ErrorNumber)
});
```

The property ErrorNumber is the actual integer value and the ErrorNumberString is the string representation of the value. I use the `nameof` expression in order to make refactoring names of properties more safe.

### Alternatively

If you just want to use the string representation to format the text correctly you could try to use the `StringFormat` property on the `Binding` object instead. Your binding initialization could look like this:

```
Binding = new Binding(nameof(DeviceLogRowVM.ErrorNumber)) { StringFormat = "ER-{0}" },
```

This will also by default (without the use of the `SortMemberPath` property) sort the column correctly as the bound value is actually an integer which just get formatted before displaying it. Useful if you only want to show 2 decimal digits of a float but needs to sort by the full precision.